# Custom query with Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently trying a custom query with Elementor, but it's not working.

I also tried a basic one (the example of the official website) and it's not working neither :

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
} );
```

Also, if I do `var_dump($query)`, I have a query on another post.

Thanks for your help,
Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

In the elementor page, when you select the 'Source' query you cannot select the 'Current Query'. Just select any other option and the Query ID should be working. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhglH.png)

You can also try with add_filter instead of add_action.